# Iframe pages in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, string, google-apps-script, iframe

I am attempting to have 2 pages in apps script. One is a home page, the other is being iframed in the home page. How do I go about doing this? (Note: must be different files, due to the second iframed file being very large and having many `, ", and '; too many to escape all of them)(I tried using a js string escaper and my PC crashed)

Comment: I think you might need two separate projects so the you could have separate end points.  I've never tried it and I don't have any interest in doing it myself.

Comment: I now feel stupid that I didn't think of this already. If you post an answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: Like I said I have no interest in the outcome so I have no motivation to do the work.  If  you want it then I recommend doing it yourself

Comment: No, I mean say "You could host the iframed page on a whole new project", and I would accept it.